# how does list modification works in python

Tags: python, list

I have list of 10 elements having a tuple of 2 elements I want to add to each tuple a value but when i write the following code to do so it seems that cumulative sum is caluculated . How is this happening. please help

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
i=0
k=10
count=[]
value=[1,2]
while i < k:
  count.append(value)
  i=i+1
t=[10,2]
i=0
#for item in count:
  #print item
while i <(len(count)):
  count[i][0]+=t[0];
  count[i][1]+=t[1];
  i+=1;

for item in count:
  print item
```

outpus is coming out to be

```
[101, 22]
[101, 22]
[101, 22]
[101, 22]
[101, 22]
[101, 22]
[101, 22]
[101, 22]
[101, 22]
[101, 22]
```

where as i expected it to be

```
[11, 4]
[11, 4]
[11, 4]
[11, 4]
[11, 4]
[11, 4]
[11, 4]
[11, 4]
[11, 4]
[11, 4]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because you actually have a list of ten references to the same (single) 2-item list. You are repeatedly adding to that same list in the second loop. You really want a new instance of a the sublist (and what you really have is a mutable list, not a tuple).

You could do this:

```
while i < k:
  count.append(value[:])
  i=i+1
```

To get new copies of the embedded list.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
i=0
k=10
count=[]

while i < k:
  count.append([1,2])
  i=i+1

t=[10,2]
i=0

while i <(len(count)):
  count[i][0]+=t[0];
  count[i][1]+=t[1];
  i+=1;

for item in count:
  print item
```

The problem was in this line: `count.append(value)`, you were adding *the same* mutable reference to `[1, 2]` to the `count` list, and kept updating it over and over again.

By replacing the line with `count.append([1,2])` you make sure that each time a new, different list is added.

And by the way, you're not using tuples (as stated in the question) anywhere in your code, only lists.

Comment: yes it works...but y above code does not work ?? I have to use a list in a program that will have variable values so i cannot code like this

Comment: @manyu I just updated my answer with the explanation, I hope it's clear now.

Comment: @manyu With this solution you'll _still_ have lists with values that can be changed during the program, so it's not clear what the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in how python uses memory, each time you append value to count, you're actually appending a reference to value's memory location. Whats happening is t[0] is being added to value[0] each time you loop through it.  See it action below (same setup you used)

```
n [54]: for i, item in enumerate(count):
print count[i];
count[i][0] += t[0]
print count[i]
....:     
[1, 2]
[11, 2]
[11, 2]
[21, 2]
[21, 2]
[31, 2]
[31, 2]
[41, 2]
[41, 2]
[51, 2]
[51, 2]
[61, 2]
[61, 2]
[71, 2]
[71, 2]
[81, 2]
[81, 2]
[91, 2]
[91, 2]
[101, 2]
```

Instead for the output you want append just the list object itself [1,2] without assigning it to a variable.

Also, enumerate() (a python built-in) produces the index number and the item in the loop so you don't have to use the whiles everywhere.